# C# an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or Property - Speech Synthesis

Tags: c#, methods, reference, uwp

I tried to build a test app using this code [example](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/23/using-speech-in-your-uwp-apps-from-talking-to-conversing/)

I define a public class as per below:

```
 public class iSpeech
 {
    // Performs synthesis
    public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> SynthesizeTextToSpeechAsync(string text)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream stream = null;
        using (SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            VoiceInformation voiceInfo =
              (
                from voice in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
                where voice.Gender == VoiceGender.Male
                select voice
              ).FirstOrDefault() ?? SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;

            synthesizer.Voice = voiceInfo;
            stream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
        }
        return (stream);
    }

    // Build audio stream
    public async Task SpeakTextAsync(string text, MediaElement mediaElement)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await this.SynthesizeTextToSpeechAsync(text);
        await mediaElement.PlayStreamAsync(stream, true);
    }
}
```

From the application main page, I then tried to call as:

```
    public async void btnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await iSpeech.SpeakTextAsync("test speech", this.uiMediaElement);
    }
```

I keep on getting

> "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or Property..." error.

Could someone please let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iSpeech` is a class, but you need an *instance* of the class in order to use non-static methods.

Think of it like `List<string>`. You can't call

```
List<string>.Add("Hello");
```

because `List<string>` is a class, like the blueprint for creating an object. (You would get the exact same error.) You would need to create an instance of that class to use it:

```
var myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Hello");
```

So in the case of your class, `iSpeech`, if you declared

```
var mySpeechThing = new iSpeech();
```

then `mySpeechThing` would be a variable representing an instance of `iSpeech`, and then you could do

```
await mySpeechThing.SpeakTextAsync("test speech", this.uiMediaElement);
```

Sometimes a class has methods that can be called without modifying the state of the object (like calling `Add` on a `List<string>` changes its state by adding a string to it.) We declare those as `static` methods. They belong to the class, not to an instance of the class.

To do that you would put the keyword `static` in the method declaration like this:

```
public static async Task SpeakTextAsync(string text, MediaElement mediaElement)
```

Then you could use it the way you were trying to.

`static` methods cannot access non-static class properties or methods. And although some may disagree, it's generally better practice not to use `static` methods. They're not evil, but until you're more familiar I'd lean the other way.

Comment: Many thanks Scott, this is exactly what I needed. 
    var mySpeechThing = new iSpeech(); await mySpeechThing.SpeakTextAsync("test speech", this.uiMediaElement);

Comment: You're welcome! Hair-splitting detail: to make code more consistently readable it's recommended to make classes start with upper case letters. And unless it's a word that starts with "I", prefacing a type name with "I" is usually used for interfaces. (But there are obviously no rules.)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "static" keyword in the Method SpeakTextAsync.

```
public static async Task SpeakTextAsync(string text, MediaElement mediaElement)
{
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await this.SynthesizeTextToSpeechAsync(text);
    await mediaElement.PlayStreamAsync(stream, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alan. Unfortunately, this.SynthesizeTextToSpeechAsync cannot be static and return error. The next reply solved it.